# How to replace the past word with the current word

Tags: r, text, nlp, lemmatization

What commands should I use when replacing a past word with a present word?

got, gotten, (getting) -> get

go, went (going)->go

thought -> think

bought -> buy

I want to replace it with the current word in this way.

I would appreciate your advice on my code.

```
library(tm)
library(XML)
crudeCorp<-VCorpus(VectorSource(readLines(file.choose())))
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, stripWhitespace)
```

I knew that the following command would change the past verb into the present form. However, after I entered this command, I looked at it. There is still a past word.

```
crudeCorp <- tm_map(crudeCorp, stemDocument)
```

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you. 
I fixed it.

Comment: No one can run your code be as no input was supplied and the expected output is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stem words :

```
docs <- tm_map(crudeCorp , PlainTextDocument) 
    tm_map(docs, stemDocument, "english")
```

Comment: I am really sorry that I forgot to mention the example of the question. How do you handle words about "think", "buy"?